# Transforming a correlation matrix to a 3 column dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, correlation

I have a correlation matrix like so

```
    a     b   c
  a 1    0.5  0.3
  b 0.5   1   0.7
  c 0.3  0.7  1
```

And I want to transform this into a dataframe where the columns are like this:

```
Letter1   letter2   correlation
   a        a           1
   a        b           0.5
   a        c           0.3
   b        a           0.5
   b        b            1      
   .        .            .
   .        .            .
```

Is there a pandas command to allow me to do this? Thanks in advance

And a follow up to this, can I assign a value to the letters in Letter1 like so:

```
 Value1 Letter1  Value2 letter2   correlation
  1        a       1      a           1
  1        a       2      b           0.5
  1        a       3      c           0.3
  2        b       1      a           0.5
  2        b       2      b            1      
  .        .       .      .            .
  .        .       .      .            .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['Letter1','Letter2','correlation']
print (df1)
  Letter1 Letter2  correlation
0       a       a          1.0
1       a       b          0.5
2       a       c          0.3
3       b       a          0.5
4       b       b          1.0
5       b       c          0.7
6       c       a          0.3
7       c       b          0.7
8       c       c          1.0
```

And then [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) columns by positions filled by [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html)ed values:

```
df1.insert(0, 'Value1', pd.factorize(df1['Letter1'])[0] + 1)
df1.insert(2, 'Value2', pd.factorize(df1['Letter2'])[0] + 1)

print (df1)
   Value1 Letter1  Value2 Letter2  correlation
0       1       a       1       a          1.0
1       1       a       2       b          0.5
2       1       a       3       c          0.3
3       2       b       1       a          0.5
4       2       b       2       b          1.0
5       2       b       3       c          0.7
6       3       c       1       a          0.3
7       3       c       2       b          0.7
8       3       c       3       c          1.0
```

Comment: Brilliant... Thanks very much

Comment: Just as a follow up is it possible to make a new column with values corresponding to letter 1. For example, the new column would have 1 for every time Letter1 is a, and 2 for every time Letter1 is b? Thanks

Comment: Do you think `[a, a, correlation]` ?

Comment: @toothsie - Can you add it to question?