# Change correlation matrix pandas df format in order to save in database

Tags: python, pandas

I have a correlation matrix that looks like this:

```
              A        AA  ...      ZYME      ZYNE      ZYXI
0             A  1.000000  0.232455  ... -0.405043 -0.564619 -0.294693
1            AA  0.232455  1.000000  ... -0.539990  0.328284  0.810599
2          AAAU -0.517470 -0.649463  ...  0.334827  0.078683 -0.340102
3          AACG -0.262797  0.102704  ...  0.184302  0.458742  0.207032
4          AADR  0.455388  0.121338  ...  0.310619 -0.221583 -0.226626
5           AAL  0.330470  0.957491  ... -0.700888  0.177816  0.731564
6          AAMC -0.741607  0.192123  ...  0.340565  0.763344  0.527503
7          AAME -0.202228  0.241567  ... -0.250411  0.193994  0.341446
```

I want to change the format of this df so that it appears in 3 columns with the first 2 columns showing the ticker pairs and the third column showing the correlation value.

I have tried using stack as suggested here:  [Transforming a correlation matrix to a 3 column dataframe in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53469212/transforming-a-correlation-matrix-to-a-3-column-dataframe-in-pandas), but I end up getting this:

```
        ticker1     ticker2 correlation
0               0  Unnamed: 0           A
1               0           A           1
2               0          AA    0.232455
3               0        AAAU    -0.51747
4               0        AACG   -0.262797
5               0        AADR    0.455388
6               0         AAL     0.33047
7               0        AAMC   -0.741607
8               0        AAME   -0.202228
9               0         AAN    0.170759
```

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

corr = pd.read_csv("corr.csv")
print(corr)

df1 = corr.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['ticker1','ticker2','correlation']
print(df1)
```

Any help appreiciated

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

The index col was causing the issues. so to resolve it I have made the first column the index here is my code

import pandas as pd

```
corr = pd.read_csv("corr.csv",index_col=0)

df = corr.rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
# print(df)


print("df1")
df1 = df.stack().reset_index()
df1.columns = ['ticker1','ticker2','correlation']
print(df1)
```

Comment: Had the same problem, thanks for updating your question with the solution!